# Using CSS Flex property to center one element and align the other element to the left or right

Tags: html, css

to center one of the two elements inside an element with CSS flex property and align the other to the left or right, what approach should I take?

When I ask ChatGPT, it gives the margin-left and margin-right properties to auto for the element that will be aligned to the right. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can utilize the CSS position property to meet your desired layout.
Please check below example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Flexbox Example</title>
<style>
    .container {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .centered-item {
        /* No specific styling for centered item */
    }

    .right-aligned-item {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px; /* Adjust this value as needed */
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="centered-item">
        Centered Item
    </div>
    <div class="right-aligned-item">
        Right Aligned Item
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Thank you very much for your help, wish you good work :)

Comment: You're very welcome! :) Happy coding! I'm thrilled it worked out for you!